# Testing native dynamic SQL in Oracle before execution

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I have implemented a certain feature in my application where the user can compose queries dynamically from the user interface by pushing around buttons and inserting some values here and there.

The user will not see the generated SQL statement at all.

I was wondering if there is a way to perhaps check the syntax and grammar *(e.g. he opened a parantheses '(' and forgot to close it )* of the dynamically generated SQL to ensure that no **run-time  compilation errors** would happen before actually executing the statement using [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`dbms_sql.parse` procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm#i997676) to parse the SQL statement assuming the statement is DML not DDL.  It would be rather unusual to parse a dynamic SQL statement using the `dbms_sql` package and then use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to execute it rather than using `dbms_sql.execute` but nothing prevents you from mixing `dbms_sql` and `execute immediate`.

The code to just parse the SQL statement would be something like

```
DECLARE
  l_cursor integer;
  l_sql_stmt varchar2(1000) := <<some SQL statement>>;
BEGIN
  l_cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  dbms_sql.parse( l_cursor, l_sql_stmt, dbms_sql.native );
  dbms_sql.close_cursor( l_cursor );
END;
```

Comment: You are correct that mixing the two isn't a common practice, but the procedure seems to do the job and its a good trade-off. Plus the name says it all. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `explain plan`, this is basically doing the first step of the execution.

```
SQL> explain plan for select * from dual;

Explained.
```

SQL is valid, you can also use the explain tables to get the tables, views etc, maybe even estimated run time ...

```
SQL> explain plan for select * from duall;
explain plan for select * from duall
                               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

SQL is invalid, this is why ...

you can also use it in a dynamic statement

```
SQL> begin execute immediate  'explain plan for ' || ' select * from dual'; end;
  2  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: It looks like a working solution although I haven't tested it, nevertheless I chose the other solution as the procedure name conveys what it is actually doing which not the case for `explain plan`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As always use error-handling, e.g. write a little error log creater package or procedure what u call when it's needed.

```
DECLARE

  my_stmt      VARCHAR2(4000):='this will contain my statements';

BEGIN

  'begin' || my_stmt || 'end'; 

EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
   prc_my_error_log_creator();
END;
```

in the log_creator use for example the DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE() func to get the stack's contain.

Regards